How to Sync Salesforce Custom Objects Linked to Either Lead or Contact?
TL;DR:
How can we sync a Salesforce custom Customer_Interaction object (linked to both Lead and Contact) with Marketo to create Smart Lists that filter on both parent and child object fields, without creating additional objects or modifying core objects in Salesforce? We use the native Salesforce-Marketo Connector/Sync method.
Details:
Salesforce Objects:

Lead
Contact
Customer_Interaction (custom object, has two "foreign keys" that link
it to either Lead (LeadID) or Contact (ContactID))

Requirements:

Each Lead/Contact can have multiple Customer_Interaction records (or none).
Sync these objects with Marketo to create Smart Lists filtering on both parent (Lead/Contact) and child (Customer_Interaction) fields.

Smart List Examples:

Leads living in "Alberta" with at least one Customer_Interaction in Product X created in the last 30 days.

Contacts living in "Ontario" with at least one Customer_Interaction in Product X and another in Product Y created in the last 30 days.


Constraints:

We would like to avoid adding objects in Salesforce solely to support Marketo integration.

We would like to avoid adding custom fields to Lead/Contact just to support Marketo integration.


Challenges (According to my investigations):

Marketo’s limitation: a Salesforce custom object can link to only one parent object in Marketo.

Link Fields in Marketo don’t work on custom objects synced from Salesforce, only on custom objects created directly in Marketo.


Questions:

How can we setup this in Marketo to meet our requirements?

Any best practices or workarounds without violating constraints?

Is splitting Customer_Interaction into two objects (one for Lead and one for Contact) in Marketo the only viable solution for this problem?


Thanks for your insights!


https://architect.salesforce.com/decision-guides/trigger-automation

You've already done most of the legwork in your question--so I don't think this answer is going to surprise you too much.
There's no one good elegant solution for needing to connect an object that links to both Lead and Contact records with Marketo. The two major options are usually to define the custom object as two distinct objects for Leads and Contacts (which you alluded to) and use the platform's native sync or to create a Marketo-based custom object and use an ETL process and Marketo's API to populate the custom objects periodically. I've done both approaches in the past, and I wouldn't argue that one is necessarily "better" than the other; it's more a case of how you need to use the custom object. The use cases you gave were all Smart List-related; if you're not looking to pull the data out of the custom object for things like email scripting, you could also consider a solution where you took something like declarative rollup summaries and made flat fields on the Lead/Contact objects that extracted what you needed.
Best of luck, no matter which path you choose to go down.
